# Computing $\lim_{x\to2}{\frac{x^3-8}{x-2}} $ via a $\delta$-$\varepsilon$ proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

It's quite evident that $x-2$ divides $x^3-8$ given that $x\neq2$. Since I'm not interested in evaluating $\frac{x^3-8}{x-2}$ at $x=2$ I have that $\frac{x^3-8}{x-2} = x^2+2x+4$. I've used the $\delta$-$\varepsilon$ definition to prove the limit of a quadratic polynomial  before but that one had real roots and this one does not. I proved the limit of the other quadratic by factoring it and then continuing on with the proof. I have not studied complex analysis and I don't belive the author of my book expects that reader to have done so either. So how can I continue the proof? Clearly the limit is $12$ but I just don't know how to prove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prove the limit of $x^2 + 2x+4$ is $12$, and $\Big(x^2+2x+4\Big) - 12$ has real roots.
$$
\Big(x^2+2x+4\Big) - 12 = x^2+2x-8 = (x-2)(x+4).
$$
If we decide in advance that $\delta$ will be no bigger than $1$, then $|x-2|<\delta$ implies $1<x<3$, so $5<x+4<7$, and so $|x+4|<7$.  That means
$$
|(x-2)(x+4)| < 7|x-2|.
$$
That should tell you what $\delta$ is, i.e. it's either $1$ or a certain thing depedning on $\varepsilon$, whichever is less.

Comment: Oh right, of course. Thank you. But just out of curiosity, had it not had real roots, would the only way to go about proving the limit have been via complex analysis or would there have been another way?

Comment: @david : Suppose you want to prove $\lim\limits_{x\to a} p(x) = L,$ and $p(x)$ is a polynomial function of $x$.Then you can factor: $p(x) - L = (x-a)(\cdots\cdots\cdots). \qquad$

Comment: And not much in this depends on whether the numbers are real. Complex analysis isn't involved until you get to things that are essentially different when non-real complex numbers are used. You're not there yet. Here's a simple example: The power series $$\displaystyle f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-c)^n $$ converges if the distance $|z-c|$ is less than the radius of convergence, and a theorem says the radius of convergence is the distance from $c$ to the nearest point to $c$ within $\mathbb C$ at which $f(z)$ cannot be extended to a differentiable function of $z$. I know of no$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$similar theorem involving only real numbers. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** $(x^2+2x+4)-12=x^2+2x-8=(x-\text{?})(x-\text{?}).$ Now use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument.